# Qt: Can we change a resource content at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, binaryfiles

In Qt, I want to read/write some information (ex: the last time the user run the app, ...) from/to a (text) resource. Can I do that in Qt? I don't want to store those information in registry or other file.

Comment: Nope, resources are read only.

Comment: Use `QSettings` for that. Your app ressources is read-only.

Comment: Even if Qt would allow modification of the resource, in sane system-wide installations, .exe and .dll are read-only to the user running them anyway.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you use for the development, Widget or QML. There are existing several methods. 
For example if you write with QML, you can use LocalStorage to save your settings. 
For Widgets existing QSettings.

An other method is, you can use [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/)([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)) for saving app settings. You don't need an database client/server or whatever, you save all your settings in a db file.

Here you can find some other methods: [Qt data-storage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-data-storage.html)

Comment: Storing externally, out side my own binary is well. I can do that. Storing using QSetting on Window is storing on registry too, as I known. I just want to store in my own binary file in this case (Qt resource).